In Azure AI. How to increase the timeout of the Job created to build a custom Dockerfile environment
When creating a Custom environment using a Dockerfile, a Job is created to build the environment. This job is created with a timeout of 1.5 hours and the build takes more than that. This leads to the Job being killed.
How can the timeout of this Job be changed?
Command Used to create the custom environment, using python SDKv2:
# Create Environment from Dockerfile
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment, BuildContext


env_docker_context = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(path="/<Folder_Containing_Dockerfile>/"),
    name="new_env",
    description="Environment, using Dockerfile.",
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_context)

Dockerfile:
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.04-py3

WORKDIR /home

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir ninja && \
    pip3 install --no-deps -v -U git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers.git@v0.0.16#egg=xformers

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1 git -y


RUN git clone https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv.git && \
    git clone https://github.com/baaivision/EVA.git


WORKDIR /home/mmcv
RUN git checkout v1.7.1
RUN pip install -r requirements/optional.txt
RUN MMCV_WITH_OPS=1 pip install -e .
RUN pip install mmsegmentation==0.29.1


WORKDIR /home/EVA/EVA-02/asuka
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


WORKDIR /home/EVA/EVA-02/det
RUN sed -i '230s/.*/            results, _ = self.roi_heads(images, features, proposals, None)/' /home/EVA/EVA-02/det/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py && \
    python -m pip install -e .

RUN pip install yapf==0.40.1 wandb scipy einops

WORKDIR /workspace

CMD ["bash"]

Returned Error:
AzureMLCompute job failed
ReceivedTerminationSignal: Job was terminated due to: Runtime received an OS termination signal.
    : Some(true)

Erro code screenshot

How you creating the custom environmet? is it through sdk, cli or portal?

Please add the error screenshot and dockerfile details.

@JayashankarGS I I edited the post with the asked clarifications

I have added the solution kindly check it

Timeouts for the build jobs are not configurable. You get 90 minutes at most. Usually, timeouts indicate dependencies conflicts when resolver struggles to satisfy the requirements. Some practices that can help with that are to avoid partial environment resolution by combining dependencies into single spec, either conda yaml or requirements.txt; pin package versions; make sure that interpreter version in active environment is within a range of what your dependencies support. If your image requires to build binaries or additional system libraries, it might have sense to decouple those into a base image and install only python layer through AzureML Environment.

Go to the job created for preparing image.

click on Edit and submit, then you will get an option in basic settings
to change timeout.

Change the timeout and submit the job.
This job is created using the command job type which takes an parameter timeout
Since, this job created automatically you can not pass it the below code, so you can edit the job in portal as shown above.
env_docker_context = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(path="/<Folder_Containing_Dockerfile>/"),
    name="new_env",
    description="Environment, using Dockerfile.",
)


When I tried this solution, I got the following error:
Execution failed. User process 'python' exited with status code 2. Please check log file 'user_logs/std_log.txt' for error details. Error: python: can't open file 'script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Yeah. i given how to update timeout in portal and re submit the job. check it.

I am just saying as of know through above code you can not set the timeout property, if any is there i will update.

After editing the timeout and re-submitting the Job, the following error is returned:
Execution failed. User process 'python' exited with status code 2. Please check log file 'user_logs/std_log.txt' for error details. Error: python: can't open file 'script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

After creating environment i hope you will use that in command job right? if yes there you set timeout and give the current environment which is getting failed to build. sample code.
`from azure.ai.ml import command, Input
define the command
command_job = command(
code="",
command="echo hi from command",
environment="docker-context-example:1",
timeout=10800
)
returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(command_job)`

also can give environment object directly
command_job = command(     code="",     command="echo hi from command",     environment=env_docker_context,     timeout=10800 )
